# Command to find out if my RAM is either DDR2 or DDR3

Tags: linux, memory, fedora

I'm using Fedora 14 on a HP Netbook 210 Mini.

My netbook had 1 GB of DDR3 memory. That wasn't enough so I decided to replace the 1 GB with a 2GB or DDR3.

What command can I issue to be sure that I am using DDR3?

I tried the following: `cat /proc/meminfo`.

However, it didn't list any information about DDR3.

Is there some other command I can use?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Running `dmidecode` or `lshw` should show the type. Might require root privileges to check, however.

Comment: Found it using dmidecode. However, lshw return 'command not found'.

Comment: It is well known that `dmidecode` is inaccurate in reporting memory information. [See here](http://www.linuxtoday.com/infrastructure/2004113000626OSHWHL)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, your comment is wrong and your link is dead. Instead of posting such tiny comments, consider posting an answer of your own with more details than can fit in the tiny comment field. :)  (For example, if dmidecode *were* inaccurate, what would you use *instead?* That would make a good answer.)

Comment: @Quuxplusone The comment was correct and the link was live when it was made. Unfortunately, you can't edit comments years later, so it's impossible to keep them up to date. If I had better information at the time, I would have left an answer rather than just a comment. But I didn't, and I felt it was important to warn anyone reading the answer that they couldn't rely on the information dmidecode gives.

Comment: to just get memory info, you can use `dmidecode -t memory` or `lshw -c memory`

Comment: If `dmidecode` doesn't list `DDR` anywhere, can I infer this information from any other bits of data?

Answer (score 19):

According to [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18372/how-can-i-find-out-what-ram-a-computer-system-has), the one-liner you're looking for is:

```
sudo lshw -short -C memory
```

This will spit out something along the lines of

```
H/W path              Device     Class          Description
===========================================================
/0/0                             memory         64KiB BIOS
/0/4                             memory         256KiB L1 cache
/0/5                             memory         1MiB L2 cache
/0/6                             memory         8MiB L3 cache
/0/7                             memory         8200MiB System Memory
/0/7/0                           memory         4GiB DIMM DDR3 Synchronous
/0/7/1                           memory         DIMM [empty]
/0/7/2                           memory         4GiB DIMM DDR3 Synchronous
/0/7/3                           memory         DIMM [empty]
/0/7/4                           memory         8MiB FLASH
```

Be aware that the human-readable string `4GiB DIMM DDR3` is self-reported by the RAM and/or BIOS, so it isn't in any standardized format. If you're really lucky, it will explicitly say `DDR3` or `DDR4`. Otherwise, if it indicates a frequency in MHz, you can try to distinguish based on that.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_dynamic_random-access_memory#Generations_of_SDRAM):

```
DDR1: 2.5 V, 133–200 MHz
DDR2: 200–400 MHz
DDR3: 1.5 V, 400–800 MHz (up to 1400 MHz for super-high-end)
DDR4: 1.2 V, 2133–4266 MHz
```

For example: My other computer's DDR4 RAM shows up in `lshw -short -C memory` as simply `16GiB DIMM Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)`. The MHz rating indicates that it's almost certainly DDR4.

Also mentioned in the [Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18372/how-can-i-find-out-what-ram-a-computer-system-has): As an alternative to [`lshw`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lshw), you can use [`dmidecode`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/dmidecode.8.en). Here's shortened example output of `dmidecode -t memory`:

```
Physical Memory Array
        Location: System Board Or Motherboard
        Maximum Capacity: 16 GB
        Number Of Devices: 2

Memory Device
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 8 GB
        Form Factor: SODIMM
        Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
        Bank Locator: BANK 0
        Type: DDR3
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 1600 MT/s
        Manufacturer: Micron
        Serial Number: 17CE52BA
        Asset Tag: 9876543210
        Part Number: CT102464BF160B.M16
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the exact way to find out whether you have DDR2 or DDR3 Memory on Debian or Ubuntu systems:

```
sudo dmidecode | grep DDR
```

It will return something like this:

```
Type: DDR3
```

Or you can do this:

```
sudo lshw | grep DDR
```

It will return a bit more information, like this:

```
description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
```

You're welcome.

Comment: As noted in the comment posted more than two years ago, to Sathya's answer posted more than three years ago, dmidecode is inaccurate. And lshw wouldn't work for the original poster.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to find type and speed of RAM on Linux:

```
sudo dmidecode --type 17|agrep -i 'speed|size|type'
```

Tested on Cent OS, Fedora, RHEL, Scientific Linux